# Write to SIM card C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-8, sim-card

I am at a hackatone and I need to do a Windows Phone app. What I need to do is to write some entries to the SIM card. I have been searching a lot, but I only found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446543.aspx that seems to somehow suit my needs, however I have no idea how should this be actually implemented.
Do you know any other solution for writing data to SIM cards in C#, or can you help me understand how to use the information in the link?

I am at the very beginning in C# so I don't really know much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link is not for Windows Phone, it is for Windows Mobile. There is no way to write to a SIM card in Windows Phone.